# The object as a method's return value in ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

ClassA:

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject
-(void)methodA;
@end

#import "ClassA.h"
@implementation ClassA
-(void)methodA
{
   ClassB *classB = [[ClassB alloc] init];
   __weak NSDictionary *dic = [classB parseFile:@“AAAA”];  
   NSLog(@“1:%@",classB);
   NSLog(@“2:%@“,dic);
   classB = nil;
   NSLog(@“3:%@",classB);
   NSLog(@“4:%@",dic);
}
@end
```

ClassB:

```
@interface ClassB: NSObject
-(NSDictionary *)parseFile:(NSString *)path;
@end

#import "ClassB.h"
@implementation ClassB
-(NSDictionary *)parseFile:(NSString *)path
{
    NSDictionary *dicB = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"221",@"111", nil];
    return dicB;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
}
@end
```

NSLOG：

```
2014-02-15 20:46:09.382 LrcTest[4309:70b] 1:<LRCParser: 0x8c12240>
2014-02-15 20:46:09.383 LrcTest[4309:70b] 2:{
    111 = 221;
}
2014-02-15 20:46:11.081 LrcTest[4309:70b] 3:(null)
2014-02-15 20:46:11.081 LrcTest[4309:70b] 4:{
    111 = 221;
}
```

Question：

At NSlog 2, dic's only strong reference is from `classB`.
When `classB` is set to `nil`，it is deallocated.
At NSLog 4, why is dic not released? Why does it still have a value? The way I see it, it doesn't have a strong reference at this point, so it should be released.
What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 2):

**ARC**:

```
-(NSDictionary *)parseFile:(NSString *)path
{
    NSDictionary *dic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"221",@"111", nil];
    return dic;
}
```

**Without ARC**:

```
-(NSDictionary *)parseFile:(NSString *)path
{
    NSDictionary *dic = [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"221",@"111", nil] autorelease];
    return dic;
}
```

dic variable is created in autorelease pool, so it will not be deallocated until return from methodA.

Comment: So if dic variable is not as the method's return value,is it also created in autorelease pool?

Comment: @Bau-yin when you return from method the local variable is removed from stack. So you have to put it into autorelease pool and than return the variable. Otherwise (without autorelease pool) the returned  value will be nill.

Answer (score 0):

Your `classB` has no references to dictionary that it returns by `parseFile:` method. So when you set nil to `classB` it not affect to *dic pointer. It will be released just after your `methodA` will end

Comment: classB has no references to dictionary, is dic created in autorelease pool like Demchenko said?